# Null pointer exception is coming

Tags: pointers, exception, null

```
public static WebDriver getscreenshot(String path) throws Exception 
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File scrFile = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path));
    return driver;
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Well thats normal. Your have declared webdriver variable but you did not initialize it at all. Try to initialize it or get it from somewhere so it can not be null.

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(some parameters here if any);
```